# looking to migrate Java projects from tomcat 9 to tomcat 8.5 (downgrade)

Tags: tomcat8

I am looking to use an earlier version of tomcat for my project to comply with AWS supported system. So my project is using tomcat 9 and works fine. I successfully installed tomcat 8.5 on my computer and when I try to 'run on server' with eclipse I get an error.

***The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are invalid. Open the server editor and correct the invalid ports.***

Comment: If both server configurations in Eclipse run at the same time, they can not use the same ports.

Comment: thank you mister hero! hahaha! so let me try changing the port of my tomcat 8.5 brb.

Comment: I try to go in -/application/apachetomcat/conf/server.xml

I changed every appearance of port 8080 for port 8089, of port 8443 for port 8449 and of port 8009 to port 8011.

still won't work...

Comment: Eclipse has its own Tomcat configuration (usually in the `Servers` project), but you can also just double click on a server in the _"Server View"_ to change the ports an everything else.

Comment: this is simply not working... gotta be using in-use ports... where can I see ports in-use?